# Compute percentage of cents total

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a simple method that will compute 10% of a particular cent amount.  The output should be another cent amount.

Example try:

```
def percentage_cent_total
   amount = (self.total_seconds.to_f / 28799)
   total = amount * self.job.rate
   total.cents

  # not sure how to compute another amount of cents that is 10% of the total above for a fee 
end
```

Comment: ... Multiply by .1 and add?

Comment: You could just multiply by .1 and add. `total.cents + (total.cents * .1)`

Comment: … which is the same as multiply by 1.1.

Comment: Elementary school students can do it.

Comment: This is 'Murika, so not necessarily :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider in addition to the comments above about the elementary part of the question.

- This is money. You're using floats ("`to_f`") but they are not accurate; Google for details. Ruby provides alternatives. For example, `require 'bigdecimal'` and then use `BigDecimal.new(self.total_seconds.to_s)` instead of `self.total_seconds.to_f`. BigDecimal is a sledgehammer - slow - but "full" accuracy (that is, it provides arbitrary precision).
- Again, this is money. Currencies have rounding rules. Some currencies might always round down, some always up. Some round mathematically (0.5 goes up to 1, less than 0.5 goes down to zero). Some are even more complex than that. I don't know how your `#cents` method is implemented there, but hopefully it's via a mechanism which understands the rounding rules for the currency at hand.

There's a Gem you can use to cover off a lot of these concerns. It's called the "money" gem:

- https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

You can lean on the authors' expertise to reduce the burden on yourself and the risks of your implementation containing financial errors.

Stylistically speaking:

- Magic `28799` constant is gross and ought to be defined somewhere as a constant, with good explanation about how the value was determined.

So that's answering the questions it looks like you didn't even realise you had while you were trying to figure out calculating 10% `:-P`